# Is there a more capable resize module for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The standard resize module with jQuery-UI has a SE grip area for dragging east and south simultaneously, but it allows you to also just drag east or just drag south.  So if your user doesn't pay close attention to keep dragging at a 45 degree angle, they can easily drag east or south and destroy the aspect ratio of their object.

I'd like to be able to click in a small area in the SE corner and have that turn on a mode where the drag  then is automatically SE, even if you're not careful and accidentally slip and move the mouse east or south.  Is anything like this available?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just set it like this. Let me know if you are looking for something else.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#myid" ).resizable({
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9
    });
});
```

You can also use { alsoResize: 'your element' } to resize some other content with the realizable element.

To set an option:

```
$("#myid").resizable('option', 'option here');
```

Getting the ratio of an element. Here's a function you can use:

```
function gcd(a,b) {
    if(b>a) {
        temp = a; a = b; b = temp
    }
    while(b!=0) {
        m=a%b; a=b; b=m;
    } 
    return a;
}
function getRatio(x,y) {
    c=gcd(x,y); 
    return ""+(x/c)+"/"+(y/c)
}
```

Call it like:

```
getRatio(elementWidth, elementHeight)
```

It will return for ex: 4/3.

Comment: Well, that forces the ratio to 16 / 9 and the original box could be something different. Plus I only want to lock in the aspect ratio when they click first in the SE corner.  I put together a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/DWsaY/3/ that tries to change the resize options to include aspectRatio : true when the se corner is clicked, but it doesn't work.  Perhaps someone can see the problem.

Comment: so change it to whatever you need and then if it changes call the set option in jquery ui to update it.

Comment: I'm not sure how alsoResize will help me.  I worked on my jsfiddle a bit more: http://jsfiddle.net/f9Vwp/1/. Now when you hover over the se corner the resizable option is run again on the object with aspectRatio : true, and when you move off of the se corner its returned to aspectRatio:false.  It seems like this should work - but it doesn't

Comment: It might not steve I was just throwing it out there as for some reason many miss it. Think of it as being thorough!!! LOL. taking a look...

Comment: do you have a page or something with real data? somehow I feel like I'm still missing what you want. I take Stack seriously and if I help someone I want to make sure they get what they're looking for. BTW added a ratio function for you in the sample it might help you get the box's ratio.